# Ruby on Rails: :topic_id=>nil, I'm lost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

So I am working on an assignment at the moment, where I am trying to display favorited posts. I currently have the favorited post displayed, but when I click it, it doesn't doesn't redirect me to anywhere.

Here is the code I currently have:

User#show where I am currently trying to display the favorited posts:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="media">
      <br />
      <% avatar_url = @user.avatar_url(128) %>
      <% if avatar_url %>
        <div class="media-left">
          <%= image_tag avatar_url, class: 'media-object' %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
        <div class="media-body">
          <h2 class="media-heading"><%= @user.name %></h2>
          <small>
            <%= pluralize(@user.posts.count, 'post') %>,
            <%= pluralize(@user.comments.count, 'comment') %>
          </small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h2>Posts</h2>
  <%= posts_exists? %>
  <%= render @user.posts %>

  <h2>Comments</h2>
  <%= comments_exists? %>
  <%= render @user.comments %>
  <h2>Favorites</h2>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= render partial: 'votes/voter', locals: { post: post } %>
    <%= link_to post.title, topic_post_path(@topic, post) %>
    <%= image_tag current_user.avatar_url(48), class: "gravatar" %>
    <%= post.comments.count %> Comments
  <% end %>
```

The error is occuring on the following line:

```
<%= link_to post.title, topic_post_path(@topic, post) %>
```

Here is the output from the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :id=>"54", :topic_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:topic_id]):
    29:   <h2>Favorites</h2>
    30:   <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    31:     <%= render partial: 'votes/voter', locals: { post: post } %>
    32:     <%= link_to post.title, topic_post_path(@topic, post) %>
    33:     <%= image_tag current_user.avatar_url(48), class: "gravatar" %>
    34:     <%= post.comments.count %> Comments
    35:   <% end %>
  app/views/users/show.html.erb:32:in `block in _app_views_users_show_html_erb__1919900632491741904_70127642538380'
  app/views/users/show.html.erb:30:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__1919900632491741904_70127642538380'
```

Obviously Topid.id is nil, but I can't figure out why. I'm going to provide you with everything I think you could need? I know this is probably a simple nooby issue, but I've been stuck on it for nearly an entire day already.

Here is my User#Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create

    @user = User.new
    @user.name = params[:user][:name]
    @user.email = params[:user][:email]
    @user.password = params[:user][:password]
    @user.password_confirmation = params[:user][:password_confirmation]

    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Welcome to Bloccit #{@user.name}!"
      create_session(@user)
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error creating your account. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @posts = @user.posts.visible_to(current_user)
    @posts = Post.joins(:favorites).where('favorites.user_id = ?', @user.id)
    @favorites = current_user.favorites
  end

end
```

Here is my Post#Controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :require_sign_in, except: :show
  before_action :authorize_user, except: [:show, :new, :create]
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = @topic.posts.build(post_params)
    @post.user = current_user

      if @post.save
        @post.labels = Label.update_labels(params[:post][:labels])
        flash[:notice] = "Post was saved."
        redirect_to [@topic, @post]
      else
        flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
        render :new
      end
  end


  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.assign_attributes(post_params)

    if @post.save
      @post.labels = Label.update_labels(params[:post][:labels])
      flash[:notice] = "Post was updated."
      redirect_to [@post.topic, @post]
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "\"#{@post.title}\" was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to @post.topic
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error deleting the post."
      render :show
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
  end

  def authorize_user
    post = Post.find(params[:id])

    unless current_user == post.user || current_user.admin?
      flash[:error] = "You must be an admin to do that."
      redirect_to [post.topic, post]
    end
  end

end
```

Here is my Topics#Controller:

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :require_sign_in, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :authorize_user, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @topics = Topic.all
  end

  def show
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @topic = Topic.new
  end

  def create
    @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)

    if @topic.save
      @topic.labels = Label.update_labels(params[:topic][:labels])
      redirect_to @topic, notice: "Topic was saved successfully."
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error creating topic. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
    @topic.assign_attributes(topic_params)

    if @topic.save
      @topic.labels = Label.update_labels(params[:topic][:labels])
      flash[:notice] = "Topic was updated."
      redirect_to @topic
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error saving topic. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])

    if @topic.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "\"#{@topic.name}\" was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to action: :index
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error deleting the topic."
      render :show
    end
  end


  private

  def topic_params
    params.require(:topic).permit(:name, :description, :public)
  end

  def authorize_user
    unless current_user.admin?
      flash[:error] = "You must be an admin to do that."
      redirect_to topics_path
    end
  end

end
```

Here is my User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  before_save { self.role ||= :member }

  EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :name, length: { minimum: 1, maximum: 100 }, presence: true
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, if: "password_digest.nil?"
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_blank: true
  validates :email,
    presence: true,
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
    length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 100 },
    format: { with: EMAIL_REGEX }

  has_secure_password

    enum role: [:member, :admin]


  def favorite_for(post)
    favorites.where(post_id: post.id).first
  end

  def avatar_url(size)
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(self.email).downcase
    "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.png?s=#{size}"
  end

end
```

Here is my Topic Model:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :labelings, as: :labelable
  has_many :labels, through: :labelings
end
```

Here is my Post Model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :labelings, as: :labelable
  has_many :labels, through: :labelings
  has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy

  default_scope { order('rank DESC') }
  scope :visible_to, -> (user) { user ? all : joins(:topic).where('topics.public' => true) }

  validates :title, length: { minimum: 5 }, presence: true
  validates :body, length: { minimum: 20 }, presence: true
  validates :topic, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true

  def up_votes
    votes.where(value: 1).count
  end

  def down_votes
    votes.where(value: -1).count
  end

  def points
    votes.sum(:value)
  end

  def update_rank
    age_in_days = (created_at - Time.new(1970,1,1)) / 1.day.seconds
    new_rank = points + age_in_days
    update_attribute(:rank, new_rank)
  end

end
```

Any insight anyone could provide, I would be extremely grateful for. If you have the time to explain where I went wrong as well, that would be even more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> User#show where I am currently trying to display the favorited posts

But you're not setting `@topic` in your User#show action. That's why it's nil.

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @posts = @user.posts.visible_to(current_user)
    @posts = Post.joins(:favorites).where('favorites.user_id = ?', @user.id)
    @favorites = current_user.favorites

    # your @topic object is not in here?
  end
```

Since a post `belongs_to` a topic you could do something like this:

```
<%= link_to post.title, topic_post_path(post.topic, post) %>
```

Comment: Whats most frustrating, I basically had that answer hours earlier. I had:

    <%= link_to post.title, topic_post_path(@post.topic, post) %> 

I honestly thought I tried your way, but I guess I didn't. So Can I ask you why its your way rather than mine? Meaning why isn't it (@post.topic, post) rather than (post.topic, post)?